# Changing text size of p value on stat_compare_means

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I am using the below code to make a boxplot, does anyone have a way of increasing the text size of the p value?

```
p <- ggboxplot(Anti, x = "X", y = "logB",
          color = "X", palette = "Dark2",
          add = "jitter") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 20),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 15),  # Adjust the size as desired
        axis.ticks.y = element_line(size = 1.5),  # Adjust the size as desired
        legend.position = "none") +
          xlab("X") + ylab("log(B)") 
  
#  Add p-value
p + stat_compare_means()
# Change method

Anti_B <- p + stat_compare_means(method = "wilcox.test", label = "p.format", 
                             label_size = 20)
Anti_B
```

Comment: Use `size` instead of `label_size` .